# Is it safe to store my own personal access token (PAT) as a secret in a shared Github repository?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to use the Github Action [`release-please`](https://github.com/google-github-actions/release-please-action) to automatically create release PRs in my repository.

The action needs the "Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests" option enabled. But unfortunately I can't enable that yet because of an organization policy.

`release-please`'s [documentation suggests using PATs](https://github.com/google-github-actions/release-please-action?tab=readme-ov-file#github-credentials), but is it OK to use my own PAT as a secret in a repository with many collaborators?

If not, what are my alternatives? Creating a "bot" account?

Thanks